# SQL Query subquery in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have 2 tables.

Table1

```
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
|    |      |
+----+------+
```

Table2

```
+-----+-----------+------+-------+---------+
|  Id | Table1_ID | Name | Value | Created |
+-----+-----------+------+-------+---------+
|     |           |      |       |         |
+-----+-----------+------+-------+---------+
```

When I run a `SELECT * FROM Table2`, I want the `Table1_ID` to be replaced with the `name` of that item `ID` from `Table 1`, rather than the `ID`. How can I do that?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` for that.

INNER JOIN Syntax 1

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fk_id
```

INNER JOIN Syntax 2

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.fk_id
```

```
SELECT Table2.Id, Table2.Name, Table1.Name, Table2.Value, Table2.Created 
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Table1_ID
```

Recommended Readings
http://sql.sh/cours/jointures/inner-join
[https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm)

Comment: This is hilarious!

Comment: May I ask why ?

Comment: Because it was so simple solution (of course a join) and my thinking was way to complicated... :) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. That happens sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

User Inner join, Like this

```
SELECT
    T2.Id
    T1_Name = T1.Name ,--Table1_ID 
    T2_Name = T2.Name
    T2.Value
    T2.Created
    FROM Table1 T1
        INNER JOIN Table2 T2
            ON T1.ID = T2.Table1_ID
```